# How to define order of method interceptors in Guice?

Tags: methods, aop, guice, interceptor

Sometimes there's a need to know the order of method interceptors that intercept a method call in Guice. A simple example scenario would be to use guice-persist provided @Transactional method interceptor with a custom @Retry method interceptor. The retry interceptor must be run outside of the transactional interceptor to make sure the retries are not executed within the same transaction.

In Spring you could use the Ordered interface for the interceptor to make sure the transaction interceptor is executed within the retry interceptor. Is there a way to achieve the same in Guice?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Guice invokes the interceptors in the order in which they were registered. So if you define them something like this:

```
bindInterceptor(any(), annotatedWith(Retry.class), retryInterceptor);
bindInterceptor(any(), annotatedWith(Transactional.class), transactionalInterceptor);
```

or

```
bindInterceptor(any(), annotatedWith(Retry.class), retryInterceptor, transactionalInterceptor);
```

the `retryInterceptor` will be executed before the `transactionalInterceptor`.

Same applies if you have multiple modules - the interceptors from first module are executed before the interceptors of the seconds module and so on.

Comment: It's a very limited approach. If you have a module that sets up some interceptors and you need to install this module and configure an additional interceptor between the ones installed by the module, there is no way to do it.

Comment: @BrunoJCM There is a way to reorder them using the [Guice SPI](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ExtendingGuice) and its visitors, you can take a list all interceptor bindings from your modules, reorder them and then create a module with those new elements. I made something like that for ordering multibinder bindings using an Order annotation.